# [__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

This is a repeated question. But my case is different. Actually I have a code from my client which is a cocos2d-x game.

I have integrated some Ad networks to that game for updating.

I did everything, and while uploading to app store, as u know the validation is done. In this stage I am getting the error as **[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**.

I came to know that it is due to misuse of NSMutableArray to retrieve its length. But it doesn't have "length" method. But count method.

I searched the entire code and I didn't see any such usage. The game is running perfectly fine with all levels at all conditions.

`NSMutableArray` was used for **StoreKit** which is also working fine.

The Ad networks which I added recently are working fine with other five games which use the same code.

**Now I'll tell what I need.**

I need a testing technique or tool to solve these type of issues as I couldn't resolve.

Also the tool must give the stack trace or code lines which are the cause for such problems. Because I've never such errors while running/ debugging this game.

I contacted the original developer and he gave a new code which is also not uploading (with out Ads also) due the same issue. But it was uploaded before 8 months. It came to me for adding Ad networks.

Comment: OK post the stack trace and the related code (which you will find from the stack trace).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html

Comment: Put exception break point and check where the application crashes..

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray` doesn't have a method naming `length`. It has method `count` to check number of elements. So please check where you called this method on `NSArray` instance.

Comment: Cool.. So now u fixed the issue?

Comment: No I was not able to resolve the issue as didn't get errors or crashes at any level or condition. The code was already uploaded. But the update is not. Also the update doesn't use any `NSMutableArray` at all. The update is just to add Ad networks to this game. But the libraries for Ads are working fine in other games with successful uploads. Please tell me if there are any testing tolls which can give the stack trace to the error. The validation in Xcode didn't give any line of code to me.